# Cannot access the Reporting Services' Report Manager

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2008

I'm having a problem setting up Reporting Services with SQL Server 2008 R2 on a Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard machine.

- The Windows user account I use is an Administrator.
- Report Server Service account : Network Service.
- Web Service URL's IP Address/Port : 172.18.200.18:8080.

Then I managed to connect to the ReportServer DB via the Reporting Services Configuration Manager (Database > Change Credentials > Test Connection  => Test Connection succeeded).

When trying to access the Report Manager (http://172.18.200.18:8080/Reports), this is the error I get:

```
User 'DOMAIN\user' does not have required permissions. Verify that sufficient
permissions have been granted and Windows User Account Control (UAC)
restrictions have been addressed.
```

Most of the time, this is because of IE not running as an Administrator.
So I restart IE as an Administrator. Same error.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I wasn't able to access my report manager and here is what I did.

1. Open IE as an admin
2. In Tools/Internet Options/ Security/ Trusted Sites, add this

   `http://localhost`  &

   `http://mymachinename`
3. Disable UAC on my machine & update a registry key (you need to update the registry to disable the UAC).
   (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hyperyash/archive/2012/07/18/disabling-user-account-control-in-windows-8.aspx)

Once you are done with the above steps restart the machine and bingo you could now access
    `http://<Mymachinename>/reports`

Once you can access your reports URL, add your user account to the "site settings" and "folder settings".

Enable the UAC & set the registry settings value back to "1" (check the link above).

Hope this helps.